# EventListener doesn't catch buttons equally

Tags: javascript, html, dom, addeventlistener, dom-events

I'm trying to build my first calculator. When adding the eventListener, the function only *sometimes* enters the `if` statement. I.e. if I click some number it doesn't log but when I try other numbers and then the first one again it works. I really don't get this behavior.

Here you can have a look (logs to the console) https://jsfiddle.net/ert54b7z/2/

```
const keys = document.querySelector(".keypad");
keys.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.matches("button")) {
    const button = e.target;
    const key = button.dataset.key;
    console.log(key);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="keypad">
  <div class="clear">
    <button data-key="clear" class="button"><p>C</p></button>
    <button data-key="all-clear" class="button"><p>AC</p></button>
  </div>
  <div class="operations">
    <button data-key="plus" class="button"><p>+</p></button>
    <button data-key="minus" class="button"><p>-</p></button>
    // ...
  </div>
  <div class="numbers">
    <button data-key="7" class="button"><p>7</p></button>
    <button data-key="8" class="button"><p>8</p></button>
    // ...
  </div>
  <button data-key="equals" class="button equals"><p>=</p></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good intuition to use event delegation. You check for the target of the click event, but since your buttons contain paragraph tags, they become the click target if you click somewhere in the center of the buttons. Remove the `<p>` tags (they aren't needed anyway), and the keys will be logged on every click.

Answer (score 0):

You're attaching the event listener to the outer div. You need to attach it to the buttons.

```js
$('.keypad').on('click', myFunction);

function myFunction(e) {
// do stuff here
}
```

```html
<div class="">
  <div class="clear">
    <button data-key="clear" class="keypad button"><p>C</p></button>
    <button data-key="all-clear" class="keypad button"><p>AC</p></button>
  </div>
  <div class="operations">
    <button data-key="plus" class="keypad button"><p>+</p></button>
    <button data-key="minus" class="keypad button"><p>-</p></button>
    // ...
  </div>
  <div class="numbers">
    <button data-key="7" class="keypad button"><p>7</p></button>
    <button data-key="8" class="keypad button"><p>8</p></button>
    // ...
  </div>
  <button data-key="equals" class="keypad button equals"><p>=</p></button>
</div>

<!-- include jquery -->
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried your approach (also with @MaximeLaunois suggestion) but it says keys.addEventListener is not a function which is understandable because keys is a node collection and not an element?

Comment: Hi, i updated the javascript. Don't use querySelector, just use document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an HTMLCollection, not a single HTMLElement. You'll have to add the event listener to each button using a for loop

Comment: changed it to use jQuery